# gcloud app deploy but Setting traffic false current version

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am updating my code on google app engine but

```
gcloud app deploy  -v logic-demo
```

By default traffic set on this version but i don't want to do this

How can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deploy a new App Engine version without directing traffic to it by using the `--no-promote` flag, like this:

```
gcloud app deploy --no-promote -v logic-demo
```

If you prefer that new versions deployments are never promoted by default, you can also set it as default in `gcloud` for all deployment by running:

```
gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false
```

All subsequent deployment will then never be promoted. You'll need to direct traffic to it manually. For example, to send all traffic to 'v2' of service 's1', you can run:

```
gcloud app services set-traffic s1 --splits v2=1
```

Comment: gcloud app deploy --no-promote -v logic-demo working :D

Answer (score 1):

To prevent traffic from being automatically routed to the new version, use the --no-promote flag.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app

Then you will be able to migrate the trafic from the Google Cloud console.